# table of contents with no sections

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning

I am compiling a booklet of abstracts, each of which has its title. I didn't treat use the command `\section` for these titles, but now I need to put them in a table of contents. For example I have:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage


\begin{center}
\textsc{Bla bla} \\
 Author
\end{center}

 This is an abstract.

 \newpage 

 \begin{center}
 \textsc{Bla bla 2} \\
  Author 2
 \end{center}

 This is another abstract. 

 \newpage


 and so on.

 \end{document}
```

My question is: is there a way to tell LaTeX to treat these titles as if they were sections? or would I need to label them all as sections? If so, how can I edit the format of sections so that they have the format above?

Thank you!

Comment: Do they have to be numbered?

Comment: not necessarily...

Comment: What should appear in the table of contents, exactly?

Comment: It would awesome to have both the title (e.g., "Bla bla") and possibly the Author in the toc...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `\addcontentsline`:

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\newenvironment*{TOCabstract}[2]{%
    \begin{center}
        \textsc{#1}%
        \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}\par\nobreak
        #2\par
        \nobreak\smallskip
}{\end{center}}



\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\begin{TOCabstract}{The first title}{Arthur Uther Thor}
    Abstract one.
\end{TOCabstract}

\begin{TOCabstract}{The second title}{Brutus Cyclops Dull}
    Abstract two.
\end{TOCabstract}

\end{document}
```

**Addition:** A refined version, that lists the authors along with the titles, and also allows an alternative title to be specified for the ToC (as the sectioning commands do).  It uses `xparse`:

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{TOCabstract}{ o m m }{%
    \center
        \textsc{#2}%
        \IfValueTF{#1}{%
            \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1, by #3}%
        }{%
            \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#2, by #3}%
        }%
        \par\nobreak
        #3%
        \par\nobreak\smallskip
}{\endcenter}



\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\begin{TOCabstract}{The first title}{Arthur Uther Thor}
    Abstract one.
\end{TOCabstract}

\begin{TOCabstract}{The second title}{Brutus Cyclops Dull}
    Abstract two.
\end{TOCabstract}

\begin{TOCabstract}[Shorter 3rd title]{The third title, long version}
            {Jonathan Horatio Quick}
    Abstract three.
\end{TOCabstract}

\end{document}
```

Here is the output:

[image: Output of the second code sample]

Comment: that's GREAT! Grazie! :)

Comment: @RobertP.: Just a minute, I’ve made a silly mistake (`#2` in place of `#3`).

Comment: Yeah, I was about to tell you about that. Thank you

Comment: Wait - let me clarify what I need. Here's what I need each title to be like:

Title 1 (in small caps) \\
Author - Affiliation (in italics)

What I would like to put in the table of contents is Title 1 and Author.

Comment: @RobertP.: Please go on: try to implement that yourself. :-)  I’ve put you on the way, try to continue on your own: that’s the way we all have learnt to write LaTeX code—and anything else, too! :-)  Feel free to ask for hints, I’ll stay at my computer for some time… :-)

Comment: Ok - let's try this out. I need though a few clarifications: what is `o m m`? #1, #2, and #3 are `TOCabstract`, the title and the author respectively, right?

Comment: @RobertP.: First hint is free. :-)  To have a fourth argument for the affiliation, replace `\NewDocumentEnvironment{...}{ o m m }` with `\NewDocumentEnvironment{...}{ o m m m }`; this adds a fourth Mandatory argument (as opposed to Optional).

Comment: so the first arugment `o` is the optional shorter title, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44225/discussion-between-gustavo-mezzetti-and-robertp).

Comment: what I would need to do now, is to add a page with a title at the end, and add this in the contents, but without page numbers. I tried to use your code to do this - it is posted above, but I couldn't hide the page number.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti You're free to roll back your answer, if you don't approve the edit. Actually the added code is wrong under many respects. I surely would not approve that edit.

Comment: @egreg: Rolled back, thanks for your advice.

Comment: @RobertP.: Use `\addtocontents`; there’s no need to define a command, if it is a one-shot.

Comment: Sorry guys - I didn't even notice it was Gustavo's message...! My intention was to edit my post. Didn't mean to get anyone angry. I solved it anyway.

Comment: @RobertP.: Please do believe that nobody got angry… :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can have this, with `titlesec` and `titletoc`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
 \usepackage[clearempty, explicit]{titlesec} %
\newcommand\Author[1]{\\ \normalfont#1}
\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{\clearpage}
\titleformat{name = \section, numberless}[block]{\scshape}{}{0pt}{\begin{center}#1\end{center}}[\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}]
\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents{section}
     [0em] % i
     {\medskip}
     {\thecontentslabel\enspace}%\thecontentslabel
     {\scshape}
     {\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}%]

\pagestyle{plain}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage

\section*{Bla bla 1 Bla bla 1\Author{Author1}}
 This is an abstract.

\section*{Bla bla 2 \Author{Author 2}}
 This is another abstract.

 and so on.

 \end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: if i would like to add the affiliation too, would it be something like: `\newcommand\Affiliation[1]{--- \itshape#1}` to be added before the `\Author` command?